# Renaming object keys in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to rename some keys of an object according to a mapping defined in another object. I have a code segment like this, but this does not seem to work, meaning does not rename the object keys:

```js
const test = {
  id: 5,
  text: 'Plain text',
  time_created: new Date(),
};

const replacements = {
  id: 'userId',
  time_created: 'postedAt',
};

console.log(test);

function renameObjectKeys(obj, replacements) {
  Object.entries(obj, ([key, _]) => {
    if (key in Object.keys(replacements)) {
      if (key !== replacements[key]) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, replacements[key],
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key));
        delete obj[key];
      }
    }
  });
}

renameObjectKeys(test, replacements);
console.log(test);
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: @Liam I guess this is just a short code segment, and what is wrong with it, is that it doesn't rename the object keys.

Comment: and you've debugged it? What problems did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've detected two issues in your code:

1. In the `Object.entries` line, you're trying to do something like a `forEach` giving a predicate to the whole function, and `Object.entries` doesn't support your use case. So you should use `Array#forEach`.
2. In the line of `if (key in Object.keys(replacements))` you're misunderstanding `in`: this operator works on objects to determine if a given property is part of the own object or somewhere in the entire prototype chain. Thus, you should use `in` on `replacements` directly.

```js
const test = {
  id: 5,
  text: 'Plain text',
  time_created: new Date(),
};

const replacements = {
  id: 'userId',
  time_created: 'postedAt',
};

console.log(test);

function renameObjectKeys(obj, replacements) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, _]) => { // <---- (1)
    if (key in replacements) { // <---- (2)
      if (key !== replacements[key]) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, replacements[key],
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key));
        delete obj[key];
      }
    }
  });
}

renameObjectKeys(test, replacements);
console.log(test);
```

### Safer approach: don't mutate

There's a simpler approach which doesn't involve renaming these properties in place, but creating a new object without mutating the input one:

```js
const test = {
  id: 5,
  text: 'Plain text',
  time_created: new Date(),
}

const replaces = {
  id: 'userId',
  time_created: 'postedAt',
}

// Converts entries to an object back again
const fromEntries = entries => 
      entries.reduce ((o, [key, value]) => ({ ...o, [key]: value }), {})

const renameProps = (replaces, obj) => 
      fromEntries (
          Object.entries (obj)
                .map (([key, value]) => [
                  replaces.hasOwnProperty (key) ? replaces[key] : key,
                  value
                ])
      )

const renamed = renameProps (replaces, test)

console.log ('from ', test)
console.log ('to ', renamed)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, I understand.

Comment: @tinker See my update, I've provided another approach :D

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
const test = {
  id: 5,
  text: 'Plain text',
  time_created: new Date(),
};

const replacements = {
  id: 'userId',
  time_created: 'postedAt',
};

console.log("test",test);

function renameObjectKeys(obj, replacements) {
    for (var key in replacements)
    {
        var temp = test[key];
        delete test[key];
        test[replacements[key]] = temp;
    }
}

renameObjectKeys(test, replacements);
console.log("test",test);
```